# slideToggle at top to push all content below down, not overlay when other divs have different z-index?

Tags: push, z-index, show, layer, slidetoggle

I have a sliding toggle div that is hidden on page load and when a button is clicked gets revealed. The div is 250px in height and is positioned top 0px. I have also tried bottom 100% which sort of does the same thing. I am using several layers of z-index and have had to position some divs using absolute in order to get the layout I wanted. But I was hoping there is a way to push all of these divs down by 250px when the sliding toggle is revealed. I was thinking that instead of using toggle div, maybe there is a way to scroll the page to -250px so that all the content appears the same but is pushed down?

This is the css for the div I am using in case there is something that can be done here:

```
#slidingTopBar
{ 
background:#199651;
display:inline-block;
position: fixed;
height:250px;
width:100%;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:56;
}
```

The script for the toggle is being used as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slidingTopBar").hide();
$(".show_hide").css('position','absolute').show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$("#slidingTopBar").css('position','absolute').slideToggle();
}); });
```

And the toggle is being called using this html:

```
<div id="TopBar"><a href="#" class="show_hide">SHOW</a></div>
```

Which is all working, except it is overlaying the content that is already there whereas I want it to push it all down.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the clearfix method directly below the toggle div or it's wrapper should fix this:

HTML: `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

CSS: `.clearfix { clear: both; }`